# JavaScript with() function

Tags: javascript

Is `with()` part of the native JavaScript library? Which browsers support it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of the [JavaScript 1.5 specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/with). So it must be supported by major browser.

Comment: The new ECMAScript 5 edition removes the `with` statement in strict mode. Future versions will probably remove it altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is part of it. Every browser that supports JavaScript 1.5 supports it (that is all major browsers, or grade A).

However, it is [not recommended](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/) to use the with statement.

Comment: +1. `with()` just isn't worth the hassle, especially since you can accomplish pretty much the same thing more explicitly using `var d = a.b.c; d.attribute = ...;`

Answer (score 2):

Even though I do agree that it should not be used to just avoid declaring another variable (e.g.)

```
// BAD use of with is to replace this:
// some.expression.with.lots.of.dots.x = 10;
// some.expression.with.lots.of.dots.y = 20;
// with this:
with (some.expression.with.lots.of.dots) {
    x = 10;
    y = 20;
}
```

I do think that it has a reasonable use:

```
// Acceptable use of with is to close over a variable by value.
var functions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    with ({ j: i }) {
        functions[i] = function() { return j; };
    }
}
```

The other option for the closure is a nested function, which has its advantages, but I find the debug experience being better if using with.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Not a part of any native JS spec I've ever seen, and some quick Google-fu yields no result either. Not to say it isn't in there somewhere, but I'd guess that if it exists it's not well documented or supported.</del>

Edit: beaten to the punch by Philippe, and apparently my answer is wrong. I'll leave it here for humility's sake, though. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Beware that JavaScript's `with` statement should be avoided.

See: [with Statement Considered Harmful](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/)